# Insert component into existing dom tree

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a component called `SelectPeopleModal`. I want append it to dom tree programmatically.

Then I can make a help method like this:

```
public static SelectUtils {
    public static void SelectPeople(Action<People> callback) {
        // I know this is not correct in blazor.
        // But I think it is helpful to express my intention.
        var modal = new SelectPeopleModal(callback); 
    }
}
```

This can make it easier to select people, I don't need to write the component in razor component every time but just call a method.

Can anyone help me ? Thank you.

---

I do have a solution that I don't satisfied with. I posted it below.
It's not a good one, it requires rendering the component in the razor file before using it.
And I have to create many select modals, It's bad to render every modal in the root component.

I want something just like [React.createPortal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html). In winform, it's easy to do this too, just `new SelectPeopleForm().OpenDialog()`. I wonder whether I can do something similarly in blazor.

## Step 1: Create Select Container And Service

SelectContainer.razor

```cs
<SelectPeopleModal Value="OldValue"
                    Visible="ShowModal"
                    OnCancel="HandleCancel"
                    OnOk="HandleOk"/>
```

SelectContainer.razor.cs

```cs
public partial class SelectContainer
    {
        [Inject]
        private SelectService SelectService { get; set; }

        private People OldValue { get; set; }
        private bool ShowModal { get; set; }
        private Action<People> OnOk { get; set; }
        private Action OnCancel { get; set; }

        private void OpenSelectModal(SelectPayload payload)
        {
            var options = payload.Options as SelectOptions<People>;

            OnOk = payload.OnOk;
            OnCancel = payload.OnCancel;
            ShowModal = true;
            OldValue = options.OldValue;

            StateHasChanged();
        }
        
        private void HandleOk(People data)
        {
            OnOk?.Invoke(data);
        }

        private void HandleCancel()
        {
            ShowModal = false;
            OnCancel?.Invoke();
        }

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            SelectService.OnSelectEvent += OpenSelectModal;
            base.OnInitialized();
        }
    }
```

SelectService.cs

```cs
public class SelectService
    {
        internal event Action<SelectPayload> OnSelectEvent;
        public Task<(bool, People)> SelectPeople(SelectOptions<People> options)
        {
            var promise = new TaskCompletionSource<(bool, People)>(null);
            OnSelectEvent?.Invoke(new SelectPayload(typeof(People))
            {
                Options = options,
                OnOk = people => {
                    promise.SetResult((true, people as People));
                },
                OnCancel = () => {
                    promise.TrySetResult((false, null));
                },
            });

            return promise.Task;
        }
    }

    public class SelectOptions<T>
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public T OldValue { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class SelectPayload
    {
        public Type ValueType { get; init; }
        public object Options { get; set; }
        public Action<object> OnOk { get; set; }
        public Action OnCancel { get; set; }

        public SelectPayload(Type valueType)
        {
            ValueType = valueType;
        }
    }
```

## Step 2: Render the container and register the select service

App.razor

```cs
...route things
<SelectContainer />
```

Program.cs

```cs
public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

            builder.Services
                .AddScoped<SelectService>();

            var host = builder.Build();

            await host.RunAsync();
        }
    }
```

## Step 3: Inject select service and use it

WhereIUsing.razor.cs

```cs
public class WhereIUsing {
    [Inject]
    private SelectService SelectService { get; set; }

    private People currentPeople { get; set; }
    private async Task DoSomething() {
        var (ok, result) = await SelectService.SelectPeople(new SelectOptions<People>
        {
            OldValue = currentPeople,
            AllowNull = true,
        });
        currentPeople = result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Prashant Off course, look my updates.